# std::stringstream object unrecognized in std::to_string replacement function

Tags: c++, c++11, tostring, stringstream

Since std::to_string doesn't work for me, and since I'm working on a very difficult environment at the moment (I'm working on Android using a Linux terminal emulator), I've decided to leave it broken and use a user-made function instead to replace it (I've found it online).

Here's the exact code I'm using:

```
#include <sstream>

namespace patch {
    template <typename T>
    std::string to_string(const T &n);
        std::stringstream stm;
        stm << n;
        return stm.str();
    }
}
```

I'm compiling it using these tags:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

And I'm getting these errors:

```
unknown type name 'stm'; did you mean 'tm'?
                stm << n;
                ^~~
```

(then a note on `tm` being declared somewhere in `include/time.h`)

```
expected unqualified-id
                return stm.str();
                ^
```

And then also an "extraneous closing brace" error for the last brace which closes the namespace brace.

As I understand it, it doesn't recognize the line `stm << n;` as the method `operator <<` used on a `std::stringstream` object, but instead  as some variable declariation for some reason.

Why exactly am I getting those errors? Is there a way to fix them? If not, what can I use to replace even this solution?

Comment: Did you include <string>?  You're also missing an opening brace for the function and it shouldn't have a semicolon after it.

Comment: I somehow doubt that there was anything wrong with `std::to_string` to begin with.

Comment: @Retired Ninja ouch. I copied and pasted the namespace from the declaration to the definition, and I forgot to change it I guess. Anyway yes, `<string>` was included, and no, `std::to_string` wasn't found anywhere.

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/Rw8Lz7  Since you didn't post complete code without syntax errors it's hard to know what else might be wrong.

Comment: @Retired Ninja yeah, it worked after I fixed what you said in your first comment. I was responding to Biffen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a semi-colon where a left curly brace should be to open the function scope